# How to enable compatibility view in Internet Explorer by coding

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In my website text and text field is not editable in ie , when i enable compatibility view in ie ,this thing solved my problem but I want to know that is there a way to active compatibility view by coding or meta tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

add this meta inside `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Comment: I have try this nothing happend

Comment: There is no JavaScript call to change the document mode.  If you've [specified the meta tag correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx), then we'll need more information about your setup in order to help.  Please update your question to include a demo page or at least a stripped down version of your HTML.  Also, it helps to know how you're testing this.  (Are you loading from a file:// URL, through a local web server, or some other technique?  Yes, [it's relevant](http://bit.ly/1LQ5Xrq).